# How can I get the path of form, before it produced in view, Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have such problem:
I have form, that displays on every page of a web-site.  So, the action is for specified(separate) view:

```
def subscribe(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SubscriptionForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect() # there is a problem
    else:
        raise Http404
```

After success handling of form, I want to redirect a user to the page, from  which form was sent. 
But if I use `request.path` - it returns me an url that handles this form. But I need the url of a page...

Do you understand? What should I do?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: try `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('url-name'))` . `url-name` means name of the url given in `urls.py`

Comment: request.path is the current path, which is the url you are posting to in this case. If you need to know the source url you could add a GET parameter with that path. Something along the lines of action="some_url_i_post_to/?source={{request.path}}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add an additional field to your form to let your view know where to redirect to. The simplest way to do this is to add a hidden input to your form:

```
<form action="/some/url/" method="post">
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.path }}">
</form>
```

The value of `request.path` is the path of the page before the user submits the form.

In your view, you can use the parameter `next` to redirect the user back to the page they came from.

```
def subscribe(request):
    ...
    next = request.POST.get('next', '/some/default/url/here/')
    return redirect(next)
```